# Is it possible to allow a path/item to be clicked through?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

If I have two paths/items with fills (Path A, and Path B), and Path A is on top of Path B... is there a way to allow you to click through Path A and get the Path B click handler to fire?

Example [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.4/S/fZBNDoIwEIWv0tRFISEEFpAIwQ0XILpUF1AqEEqHQBMXxrvbQQxIorOan69v5vVBVd4JGtFTKzSvqUM5lFhzUKMmBWgNHUmIEndyFFznqpLCwiqDRmnL9xzfsx2y7mDLs+34otYiWa7rWQhTd1F7z5FfSPfWSJmChMG8Ybv9FOwbAZXKhrcGsGySHAhuAylcCZXF5ss5EqJkqP65R0P/x1HoOeHGUWAcBWtHRuG3HTNEcmY2RvgULDYfXQwib3vcMNLofH2+AA==). I want to be able to see the "bottom clicked" log when clicking on the overlapped corner of topPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.4/S/fZHBDoIwEER/pakHIGkIHiQRgxd+wOhRPGBdhVB2CdZ4MP67XcSIJrqndjp9nUlvEosGZCI3NVhdSiU1HXivCc9W7MlaakQqEK5iDdoWeDLg825FFVp/GqlpFCgxVliKgmCR4xiyKmw5gHgZvmnPc/a/neGxMiYjQ527403m/XifFsLMVLp2Bj8Q6VLwa2QgNHTyvSG5ZgccPKa/8lhq/zSKIxV/NZq5RrNxI0f4XeeWo3DTvYSE7eopGuI0TukukOOdiQPrq7Duhwu7L9l3UNQtZznLZLu7PwA=)**

http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#locked

> Specifies whether the item is locked. When set to true, item interactions with the mouse are disabled.

```js
const bottom = new Rectangle(new Point(10,10), new Point(100,100));
const bottomPath = new Path.Rectangle(bottom);
bottomPath.fillColor = '#999999';
bottomPath.onClick = () => console.log('bottom clicked');

const top = new Rectangle(new Point(60,60), new Point(150,150));
const topPath = new Path.Rectangle({
    rectangle: top,
    locked: true
});
topPath.fillColor = '#cccccc';
```

Comment: You are a god among men. I don't know why I didn't find this earlier. Thanks a ton!